# Scala meaning of tilde

Tags: scala

Hi I new in Scala and have a problem with following example:

```
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._

    case class Customer(id: Option[Long], firstName: String, lastName: String, birthday: Option[java.util.Date])

/**
 * Mapped customers table object.
 */
object Customers extends Table[Customer]("customers") {

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def firstName = column[String]("first_name")

  def lastName = column[String]("last_name")

  def birthday = column[java.util.Date]("birthday", O.Nullable)

  def * = id.? ~ firstName ~ lastName ~ birthday.? <>(Customer, Customer.unapply _)

  implicit val dateTypeMapper = MappedTypeMapper.base[java.util.Date, java.sql.Date](
  {
    ud => new java.sql.Date(ud.getTime)
  }, {
    sd => new java.util.Date(sd.getTime)
  })

  val findById = for {
    id <- Parameters[Long]
    c <- this if c.id is id
  } yield c
}
```

What is the meaning of line:

```
def * = id.? ~ firstName ~ lastName ~ birthday.? <>(Customer, Customer.unapply _)
```

How to interpret tilde signs and question marks?

Comment: What is `Table`? What is the type of `id`, `firstname`, etc?

Comment: Agreed with Tichodrama, we need more information about `Table` and the columns you have here. Like **all** 'operators', the `~`, `.?` and `<>` are all functions defined on a class. Have you looked at the documentation for that class to see if it tells you what those functions do? (They aren't a part of the language on its own)

Comment: this model is about to represent database table so Table is class to do so, as I think. Types of  id  is Long, firstname is String. If this is what you are asking.

Comment: Table is from package scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._

Comment: Slick no longer uses those tildes: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/schemas.html#mapped-tables

Comment: I believe the `.?` means that the id column in this case is to be handled as being optional when mapped to the case class (`Customer`)

Comment: @pmalecki - If you want more answers, add a Slick tag to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking at a Slick Table definition which follows the Slick 1.0+ version of defining the default projection of the [Table](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/api/#scala.slick.lifted.AbstractTable) using the method named `*`.  The `~`s join the [Column](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/api/#scala.slick.lifted.WrappedColumn)s to make up the default view returned in a kind of projection builder pattern.  The `?`s indicate which fields represent Option values in the Customer class and `<>` is a method name in the [Projection](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/api/#scala.slick.lifted.Projection) trait.  You can think of the `<>` as being used to take things out or put things into the database for a Customer here.  If you have something that doesn't map well, for example if that Table didn't have the implicit dateTypeMapper, the `<>` function is where you would manually adjust the values coming in and going out of the Customer case class for Date conversion.

Honestly, finding out where these methods come from is easier inside an IDE because the docs don't describe the class details and there are a lot of classes in the Slick scaladocs.

Here's a link to the [1.0.1 Lifted Embedded](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/lifted-embedding.html#mapped-tables) documentation.